# How to enable the /wrap-margin option for Intel Fortran compiler in VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I've just started learning Fortran recently. I have a problem of compiler wrapping the line with more than 80 characters in it (in the code below it divides the array on 2 lines). I've found out about `/wrap-margin` option in the Intel compiler, which can solve my problem. But as I understood it's not available in VS2022 IDE's options list. So here I have a small code that reverses array:

```
program four
implicit none
integer::i,k,l,c
integer::arr(0:7)
k=lbound(arr,dim=1)
l=ubound(arr,dim=1)
arr=[0,5,2,4,7,1,3,19]
do i=0,3
    c=arr(l-i)
    arr(l-i)=arr(k+i)
    arr(k+i)=c
end do
write(*,*) arr
pause
end program four
```

Can someone show me,please, how I can disable the wrap option in this code?

I found the Intel developers guide, where I've discovered the `/wrap-margin` option, but I couldn't find any example of working with compiler's options not presented in the IDE (VS2022)

Comment: If you care about the format and where line breaks occur in output, then avoid using list-directed output and specify the format you desire. This way, you don't need to rely on compiler-specific options, or "too much whitespace", etc.

Comment: For example, you can see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51534237/3157076), and those linked against it, for ideas about how to specify useful explicit formats.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran]. I now you were asked to indicate the "version of Fortran" you are using but your are almost surely *not* compiling your code as Fortran 90. All modern compilers are at least Fortran 95, most of them much more. Instead, tell us which compiler version you are using. Are you using Intel OneAPI? Which version? Please note that VS2022 is not a compiler, it is only an IDE, that means a text editor with functions that call the compiler for you.

Comment: Relying on a compiler option is not reliable and portable. I strongly recommend the path outlined in the above linked question. Also, I strongly recommend to learn how the compiler can be used without an IDE.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Intel Fortran compiler and VS2022 as IDE. I knew about formated output and input, but I just wanted to find out how I can work with compiler's options that are not available in VS2022 in "properties" of the solution.